# Solving a differential equation containing the absolute value of the function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation (from a larger context narrowed down):
$$\partial_t E=\left(A\cdot|E|^2+B\right)\cdot E$$
Can I simply see the absolute value as a constant, and thus reducing the formula to 
$$\partial_t E=C\cdot E$$
which results in 
$$E=E_0\cdot\exp\left((A\cdot\vert E\vert^2+B)\cdot t\right)$$
But how do I then get 
$$\vert E\vert^2=?$$
Or do I have to follow another approach?

Comment: If $E$ is real valued then $|E|^2=E^2$, and you have a Bernoulli equation.

Comment: $E$ is a complex function, thus that solution is not applicable here.